# Adding subView to iPad's UIView works incorrectly in Xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

My .xib contains a `UITabBar` and 3 views:

[image]

[image]

I made an outlet:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView* _controllersContainerView;
```

In my `viewDidLoad` method I want to add a subview to `_controllersContainerView`:

```
    [self controllersNavigationController].view.frame = _controllersContainerView.bounds;
//  [self controllersNavigationController].view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 199);
    [_controllersContainerView addSubview:[self controllersNavigationController].view];
```

But even I try to set frame height to extra short value (199) it looks longer than `_controllersContainerView` and covers the `tabBar`.

[image]

What's wrong with code? It worked fine in Xcode 4.4 with armv6 v7, but it fails in Xcode 4.5.

Comment: Drag the tabBar to the foremost (I.e. bottom) of the list of subviews.

Comment: @tkanzakic, I have no tabBarController, only TabBar and 3 views.

Comment: @CodaFi in my .xib TabBar doesn't cover any views. If I drag TabBar to the top most view, TabBar will cover _controllersContainerView. I want my views and a tabBar not to be overlapped

Answer (score 0):

Set clipToBounds property to YES, It might fix the issue.

Comment: I tried to set controllersNavigationController].view.clipsToBounds to YES before and after adding subView. No result

Comment: ClipsToBounds only applies in the case of overdraw, not a subview being higher up in the view hierarchy.